# Group_concat em JPQL

Tags: select, jpql

Criei a seguinte `query:

```
SELECT 
o.codigoChamado,
o.codigoOrcamento,
group_concat(o.conteudoOrcamento),
o.observacaoOrcamento
FROM 
Orcamentos  as o
group by
o.codigoChamado,
o.codigoOrcamento,
o.observacaoOrcamento
order by 
o.codigoOrcamento
```

Quando executada direto na base consigo obter o resultado esperado normalmente, porém essa `query` precisa ser executada via JPQL e o `group_concat` não é nativo do JPQL, há algo que eu possa substituir o `group_concat` porém ainda sim obter o mesmo retorno?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar a `FUNCTION` do JPQL para chamar funções nativas ou funções criadas no banco de dados.

Para chamá-la, você deve fornecer o nome da função no primeiro parâmetro e nos demais parâmetros você os preenche com os parâmetros que vão para a função do banco de dados.

No seu exemplo, ficaria:

```
FUNCTION(group_concat, o.conteudoOrcamento)
```

Sua consulta toda fica assim:

```
String jpql = "SELECT o.codigoChamado, o.codigoOrcamento, FUNCTION(group_concat, 
    o.conteudoOrcamento), o.observacaoOrcamento FROM  Orcamentos o
    group by o.codigoChamado, o.codigoOrcamento, o.observacaoOrcamento order by o.codigoOrcamento"
Query query = em.createQuery(jpql);
```